# PHP json url not passing correctly replacing & with &amp;

Tags: php, json

Getting this error

[Tue Aug 18 14:41:57.614006 2015] [:error] [pid 21389] [client 67.90.138.68:5794] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=BR: Vigilante Crate): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error\r\n

```
<?php
foreach($json2['rgDescriptions'] as $i){
$item = $i['market_name'];
$icon = $i['icon_url'];
$fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . $item;
$grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
$id = json_decode($grab, true);
echo '<img src="'. $imgurlbase . $icon . '/64fx64f">' . '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">' . $item . '</a>'. '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">'. $id['lowest_price'].'</a>'.'<br>';
}
```

For some reason the & in the base url is getting passed as '& amp;' each time in the url and not as &

I am not the best with php, yet nothing I am searching for is coming up with why. Does it have to do with the json_decode? That is my only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to encode the string:

```
$fetchdata = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($item);
```

works for me:

```
php > $fetchdata ='http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=295110&currency=1&market_hash_name='.urlencode('BR: Vigilante Crate');
php > $grab = file_get_contents($fetchdata);
php > print_r(json_decode($grab));
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [lowest_price] => $0.07
    [volume] => 4,994
    [median_price] => $0.07
)
```

Comment: sigh, I was focusing on the url and not the item var. Thanks man!

Comment: no probs, glad it's working :) of course, you should probably use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php to safely build the URL, but for a simple use case like yours, hardly worth it